# PHP AJAX array encoded to JSON is not displayed sorted in HTML table but it is displayed sorted in when only MySQL query is executed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have this `MySQL` query where rows are sorted according to `month` and `year` by `ASC`:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(MONTHNAME(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment), ' - ', YEAR(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment)) as assessmentDate,
    MONTHNAME(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment) as monthNameAssessment,
    YEAR(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment) as yearAssessment, 
    MONTH(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment) as monthAssessment, 
    AVG(diabetes_assessment.assessment_result) as avgAssessment
FROM 
    diabetes_assessment
WHERE
    diabetes_assessment.clinic_id = '361'
group by 
    MONTH(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment), 
    YEAR(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment)
ORDER BY yearAssessment, monthAssessment ASC
```

The result is like the one shown at [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/510573/1) and rows are displayed properly and sorted `ASC`.

```
| assessmentDate | monthNameAssessment | yearAssessment | monthAssessment | avgAssessment |
|----------------|---------------------|----------------|-----------------|---------------|
|   March - 2016 |               March |           2016 |               3 |          40.5 |
|   April - 2016 |               April |           2016 |               4 |            45 |
|   April - 2017 |               April |           2017 |               4 |            31 |
|     May - 2017 |                 May |           2017 |               5 |            40 |
```

Now I am duplicating some few columns because I will use them in `chartJs` to display some charts. Anyway, when I am using PHP to encode the rows and send them through AJAX and display them in a html table:

```
$cid = $_SESSION['clinic_id'];
$arrayResult = array();
$getAverage = "
SELECT
    CONCAT(MONTHNAME(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment), ' - ', YEAR(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment)) as assessmentDate,
    MONTHNAME(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment) as monthNameAssessment,
    YEAR(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment) as yearAssessment, 
    MONTH(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment) as monthAssessment, 
    AVG(diabetes_assessment.assessment_result) as avgAssessment
FROM 
    diabetes_assessment
WHERE
    diabetes_assessment.clinic_id = :cid
group by 
    MONTH(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment), 
    YEAR(diabetes_assessment.date_of_assessment)
ORDER BY 
    yearAssessment, 
    monthAssessment ASC";

$execGetAverage = $conn->prepare($getAverage);
$execGetAverage->bindValue(':cid', $cid);
$execGetAverage->execute();
$result = $execGetAverage->fetchAll();

$i=0;
foreach($result as $res)
{
    $arrayResult[$i] = $res;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($arrayResult);
```

And here the Ajax script:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../php/getAssessmentResultByMonth.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(resp)
        {
            $.each(resp, function(key, result)
            {
                $("#after_tr").after("<tr><td>"+result['assessmentDate']+"</td><td>"+result['avgAssessment']+"</td></tr>")
            });
        },
        error:function(resp)
        {
            console.log(resp);
        }
})
```

Now the result in the HTML table is not displaying rows sorted:

```
| assessmentDate | monthNameAssessment | yearAssessment | monthAssessment | avgAssessment |
|----------------|---------------------|----------------|-----------------|---------------|
|   March - 2016 |               March |           2016 |               3 |          40.5 |
|   April - 2017 |               April |           2017 |               4 |            31 |
|   April - 2016 |               April |           2016 |               4 |            45 |
|     May - 2017 |                 May |           2017 |               5 |            40 |
```

Comment: javascript do not maintain orders properties in object that why your html table is not displayed in sorted order

Answer (score 1):

to retain the original order make array inside array in php

change like this

```
foreach($result as $res)
{
    $arrayResult[$i][] = $res;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($arrayResult);
```

Comment: didn't worked can show the final json after making array inside array

Comment: all arays was `undefined` `undefined` ... `undefined`

Comment: console.log(resp) and see what your getting